# Row count in a single cell/row SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I'm having a hard time trying to display the count total on a report based on a "DataSet" sql query result . The script will return 2 columns , the number of columns will vary. There is a table already created (table 1) to show those 2 columns but I've created another table (table 2) with just 1 column and 1 row to display only the total count of rows from table1.

The problem is that if Table 1 has 45 rows , the table 2 will also display 45 rows and on each row the number 45 when is supposed to show only 1 row with the number 45. The expression I'm using on table 2 is `=COUNT(Fields!Full_Report_Path.Value, "ReportData")`

How can I fix this to have only one row with the 45 number on table 2?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the data set name for the Tablix to the correct dataset which is returning the single Value. Ensure you don't put that in the details line (detailed group).. If you create a text box or as part of a group then you will get only one line returned.. Hope that made sense.

Comment: Thanks Harry , I've decided to do it on that way

Answer (score 0):

I've found2 possible solutions:

1- Add text above the report table and create an expression using the following code `=Globals!ReportName &": " & RowNumber("ReportData")`

[image]
  [image]
2- Insert a new row to the report table but choosing "Outside the group" , on Column 1 I've added the word "Total" and on Column 2 the expression `=RowNumber("ReportData")`

[image]
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think you set group on details row. So please check it, you could click cell with expression, then right click "Details" in Row Group, and delete the field in Group to see whether it works or not.

Zoe